# writing to django session database table after configurating settings.py

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a new backend API using Django.

I have configured the following values in *settings.py*:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
    }
}

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
```

I can't figure out how to write the session properties to the database. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "session properties"?

Comment: session_key, session_data, expiry_date (table fields that were generated by the framework)

Comment: What do you plan to write there?

Comment: i want to write all the sessions data..

Comment: This is still really unclear. What data do you plan to write? What is "all the sessions data"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to activate also `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` middleware first to have access to `request.session` dictionary in your views.

Here's simplistic example how to use `request.session`, taken directly from Django [session documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#examples):

```
def post_comment(request, new_comment):
    if request.session.get('has_commented', False):
        return HttpResponse("You've already commented.")
    c = comments.Comment(comment=new_comment)
    c.save()
    request.session['has_commented'] = True
    return HttpResponse('Thanks for your comment!')
```